# Update paypal stored credit card details from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I was trying to update Paypal credit card details from C# code.i have `Credit_card_id` and generated `apiToken` to access Paypal.Now I'm confused to how send update data to paypal api and which function will call to update credit card details.I have updated written code below.

```
           {
            var apiContext = PaypalConfiguration.GetApiContext();
            PatchRequest patchRequest = new PatchRequest();
            Payment payment = new Payment();
            payment.Update(apiContext, patchRequest);  
           }
```